# Trouble with innerHTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am making a form with some fields that a user has to fill out. Once he/she fills it out, hits save, the form disappears and a new div appears with what the user filled out. Unfortunately, I cannot get the data to show in this second div that appears. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, maybe you can help me? Also, I need to use pure Javascript, not jQuery or anything else.

```js
var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var state = document.getElementById('select_state');
var whichState = state.options[state.selectedIndex].text;
var parname = document.getElementById('pname');
var form = document.getElementById('form_div');
var edit = document.getElementById('view_div');

if (document.getElementById('m').checked == true) {
  var Gender = 'Male';
} else {
  Gender = 'female';
}

function showData() {
  if (form.style.display != 'none') {
    form.style.display = 'none';
    edit.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    form.style.display = 'block';
  }
  parname.innerHTML = [
    firstName.name + " : " + firstName.value + "<hr>",
    lastName.name + " : " + lastName.value + "<hr>",
    state.name + " : " + state.options[state.selectedIndex].text + "<hr>"
  ].join("");
}

function editData() {
  if (edit.style.display != 'none') {
    edit.style.display = 'none';
    form.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    edit.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="form_div">
    <form>
      First Name:
      <input type="text" name="First Name" id="fname">Last Name:
      <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="lname">
      <input type="radio" name="Gender" id="m" value="male" checked>Male
      <input type="radio" name="Gender" id="f" value="female">Female
      <select name="state" id="select_state">
        <option value="select">- Please Select -</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="showData();">

  </div>

  <div id="view_div" style="display:none;">
    <button id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="editData();"></button>
    <p id="pname"></p>
  </div>

  <body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? Did you see anything?

Comment: One mistake among others: the `firstName` variable contains a string since `document.getElementById('fname').value` gives a string. Hence, you can't write `firstName.name` or `firstName.value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form_div">
        <form>
            First Name:
            <input type="text" name="First Name" id="fname">
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="lname">
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" id="m" value="male" checked>Male
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" id="f" value="female">Female
            <select name="state" id="select_state">
                <option value="select">- Please Select -</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            </select>
        </form>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="showData();">


    </div>

    <div id="view_div" style="display:none;">
        <button type="button" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="editData();">
        <p id="pname"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var firstName = document.getElementById('fname');
        var lastName = document.getElementById('lname');
        var state = document.getElementById('select_state');
        var whichState = state.options[state.selectedIndex].text;
        var parname = document.getElementById('pname');
        var form = document.getElementById('form_div');
        var edit = document.getElementById('view_div');

        if (document.getElementById('m').checked == true) {
            var Gender = 'Male';
        } else {
            Gender = 'female';
        }

        function showData() {
            if (form.style.display != 'none') {
                form.style.display = 'none';
                edit.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                form.style.display = 'block';
            }
            parname.innerHTML = [
                    firstName.name + " : " + firstName.value + "<hr>",
                    lastName.name  + " : " + lastName.value + "<hr>",
                    state.name     + " : " + state.options[state.selectedIndex].text + "<hr>"
                ].join("");
        }
        function editData() {
            if (edit.style.display != 'none') {
                edit.style.display = 'none';
                form.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                edit.style.display = 'block';
            }           
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

try this one I think it is working

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form_div">
        <form>
            First Name:
            <input type="text" name="First Name" id="fname">
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="lname">
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" id="m" value="male" checked>Male
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" id="f" value="female">Female
            <select name="state" id="select_state">
                <option value="select">- Please Select -</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="showData();">

    </div>

    <div id="view_div" style="display:none;">
        <button type="button" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="editData();">
        <p id="pname"></p>
    </div>

    <script>


        function showData() {
            var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
        var state = document.getElementById('select_state');
        var whichState = state.options[state.selectedIndex].text;
        var parname = document.getElementById('pname');
        var form = document.getElementById('form_div');
        var edit = document.getElementById('view_div');

        if (document.getElementById('m').checked == true) {
            var Gender = 'Male';
        } else {
            Gender = 'female';
        }
            if (form.style.display != 'none') {
                form.style.display = 'none';
                edit.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                form.style.display = 'block';
            }
            parname.innerHTML = [
                    " First Name : " + firstName + "<hr>",
                    " Last Name : " + lastName + "<hr>",
                    " state : " + state.options[state.selectedIndex].text + "<hr>"
                ].join("");
        }
        function editData() {
            if (edit.style.display != 'none') {
                edit.style.display = 'none';
                form.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                edit.style.display = 'block';
            }           
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var firstName = document.getElementById('fname');
var lastName = document.getElementById('lname');
```

Problem: you didn't target DOM objects, you have targeted their values, and later in code you try to get properties, like: `firstName.name`! 
Change two lines at the top of your code to this, and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One error is the fact that you are getting the values from the elements right after the page is rendered, thus they are all **undefined**.

You should get them after the save button is pressed. Moving the variable declarations inside the **showData** function will help that.

Also in your variables you are saving the **element.value**, thus saving the string entered by the user. 
Later when creating the text you are trying to insert as HTML you access the **value** and **name** properties. That means you are trying to use **element.value.value** and **element.value.name** which **undefined** for strings.

Removing the **value** property in your variable declaration will give you the **element**, and later you can just get the **value** and **name** properties out of it.

Comment: I made this plunkr with the fix. http://plnkr.co/edit/aGpI95zm7KRx5XUKxbna?p=preview